# Where do I find the Java command line tool "Gdb"?

Tags: debugging, java

Where do I find the Java command line tool "Gdb" ?   It's not included in my Sun JDK 1.6 distribution.   I need a way to take a java core dump from a live java instance.

Comment: What operating system are you trying to do this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB is the GNU Debugger. You can find it here http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: Ahhh. Doh.  I should have known that.  For some reason I was thinking "java java java..."